# How to access dynamic conditional nested object properties in an angular template?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to check something like this:
`*ngIf="charts.data['key with space']?[dynamicKey] !== undefined"`

But the compiler then appears to see this like a ternary operator..

Another option is to write it like this, but thats way longer and becomes more unreadable in longer property chains:

`*ngIf="charts.data['key with space'] && charts.data['key with space'][dynamicKey] !== undefined"`

Comment: Missing `.`. Should be `*ngIf="charts.data['key with space']?.[dynamicKey] !== undefined"`

Comment: That's it! Thanks! If you make answer I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, there is a syntax error for the optional chaining (`?.`).

It should be:

```
*ngIf="charts.data['key with space']?.[dynamicKey] !== undefined"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a method in your class to do the evaluation and then return that to the template?

`*ngIf="doesExist(charts.data['key with space'], dynamicKey)"`

Function:

```
doesExist(obj: any, key: string): boolean {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(key)
}
```

Not tested, but gives you the idea...

Comment: because methods get called an obnoxious amount of times from templates, I try to avoid those by principle. Somewhere they might cause performance issues. But it's a nice idea actually, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function and return a boolean and therefore remove the logic from the html entirely.

```
*ngIf="canShowItem(key, dynamicKey)"

canShowItem(key: string, dynamicKey: string): boolean {
 const data = charts.data[key];
 if(!data) { return false};
 return data[dynamicKey] !== undefined
}
```